# Как сделать бокове меню с помощью <select>?

Tags: javascript, меню, выпадающий-список

Есть левые и правые колонки. На мобильной версии боковое меню, с помощью которой происходит переключение, дожно превращается в подобие выпадающего меню, как на картинке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В моем коде js вроде работает, но нужно сделать так, чтобы выбранный элемент не отображался в списке, при выборе.

```js
let tabs = document.querySelectorAll("._tabs");
for (let index = 0; index < tabs.length; index++) {
  let tab = tabs[index];
  let tabs_items = tab.querySelectorAll(".sidebar__item");
  let tabs_blocks = tab.querySelectorAll("._tabs-block");
  for (let index = 0; index < tabs_items.length; index++) {
    let tabs_item = tabs_items[index];
    tabs_item.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      for (let index = 0; index < tabs_items.length; index++) {
        let tabs_item = tabs_items[index];
        tabs_item.classList.remove('_active');
        tabs_blocks[index].classList.remove('_active');
      }
      tabs_item.classList.add('_active');
      tabs_blocks[index].classList.add('_active');
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  }
}

let select = function() {
  let selectHeader = document.querySelectorAll('.sidebar__item-mobile');
  let selectItem = document.querySelectorAll('.sidebar__item');

  selectHeader.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', selectToggle)
  });

  selectItem.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', selectChoose)
  });

  function selectToggle() {
    this.parentElement.classList.toggle('_active');
  }

  function selectChoose() {
    let text = this.innerHTML,
      select = this.closest('.sidebar__nav'),
      currentText = select.querySelector('.sidebar__item-current');
    currentText.innerHTML = text;
    select.classList.remove('_active');
  }
};

select();
```

```css
._tabs-block {
  display: none;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

._tabs-block._active {
  display: block
}

.one {
  background: red;
}

.two {
  background: green;
}

.three {
  background: yellow;
}

.sidebar__list {
  list-style: none;
}

.sidebar__item-mobile {
  width: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: grey;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.sidebar__item-current {
  width: 100%;
}

.sidebar__link {
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: inherit;
}

.sidebar__list {
  width: 200px;
  height: 0px;
  background: grey;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all .4s ease 0s;
}

.sidebar__nav._active .sidebar__list {
  height: 90px;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.sidebar__item {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.left {
  margin: 0 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="user__inner _tabs">
  <div class="left">
    <nav class="sidebar__nav">
      <div class="sidebar__item-mobile">
        <div class="sidebar__item-current">1</div>
      </div>
      <ul class="sidebar__list">
        <li class="sidebar__item _active">
          <button class="sidebar__link">1</button>
        </li>
        <li class="sidebar__item">
          <button class="sidebar__link">2</button>
        </li>
        <li class="sidebar__item">
          <button class="sidebar__link">3</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="_tabs-block one _active">1</div>
    <div class="_tabs-block two">2</div>
    <div class="_tabs-block three">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант можно добавить display:none; активному итему, и контейнер растянуть на 100%

```js
let tabs = document.querySelectorAll("._tabs");
for (let index = 0; index < tabs.length; index++) {
  let tab = tabs[index];
  let tabs_items = tab.querySelectorAll(".sidebar__item");
  let tabs_blocks = tab.querySelectorAll("._tabs-block");
  for (let index = 0; index < tabs_items.length; index++) {
    let tabs_item = tabs_items[index];
    tabs_item.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      for (let index = 0; index < tabs_items.length; index++) {
        let tabs_item = tabs_items[index];
        tabs_item.classList.remove('_active');
        tabs_blocks[index].classList.remove('_active');
      }
      tabs_item.classList.add('_active');
      tabs_blocks[index].classList.add('_active');
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  }
}

let select = function() {
  let selectHeader = document.querySelectorAll('.sidebar__item-mobile');
  let selectItem = document.querySelectorAll('.sidebar__item');

  selectHeader.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', selectToggle)
  });

  selectItem.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', selectChoose)
  });

  function selectToggle() {
    this.parentElement.classList.toggle('_active');
  }

  function selectChoose() {
    let text = this.innerHTML,
      select = this.closest('.sidebar__nav'),
      currentText = select.querySelector('.sidebar__item-current');
    currentText.innerHTML = text;
    select.classList.remove('_active');
  }
};

select();
```

```css
._tabs-block {
  display: none;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

._tabs-block._active {
  display: block
}

.one {
  background: red;
}

.two {
  background: green;
}

.three {
  background: yellow;
}

.sidebar__list {
  list-style: none;
}

.sidebar__item-mobile {
  width: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: grey;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.sidebar__item-current {
  width: 100%;
}

.sidebar__link {
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: inherit;
}

.sidebar__list {
  width: 200px;
  height: 0px;
  background: grey;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all .4s ease 0s;
}

.sidebar__nav._active .sidebar__list {
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.sidebar__item {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
.sidebar__item._active {
  display: none;
}

.left {
  margin: 0 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="user__inner _tabs">
  <div class="left">
    <nav class="sidebar__nav">
      <div class="sidebar__item-mobile">
        <div class="sidebar__item-current">1</div>
      </div>
      <ul class="sidebar__list">
        <li class="sidebar__item _active">
          <button class="sidebar__link">1</button>
        </li>
        <li class="sidebar__item">
          <button class="sidebar__link">2</button>
        </li>
        <li class="sidebar__item">
          <button class="sidebar__link">3</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="_tabs-block one _active">1</div>
    <div class="_tabs-block two">2</div>
    <div class="_tabs-block three">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ) точно! Спасибо!